# Select taking so long to finish

Tags: mysql

I have this select to show follow suggestions to an user.

first it will get follows from an user, then it will check if user is not following this user. check if user did not block this suggestion and if the suggestion did not block the user and show it.

```
select c.user, c.nome, p.foto, f.user, f.following from following f

left join cadastro c ON c.id=f.following
left join profile_picture p ON c.id=p.user

where f.user in (select following from following where user = 1) and following <> 1 and following not in (select following from following where user = 1)

and (c.id not in (select `block` from block where user = 1))
and (c.id not in (select `user` from block where block = 1))

group by following order by rand() limit 4
```

any ideas to improve this? it is taking about 3.4641 secounds.

[image]

Comment: Your query have so many sub queries to execute, check your query execution plan using MySQL workbench utilities.

Comment: https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/tune-mysql-queries-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses:
2 joins, 4 nested queries, 1 grouping, and 1 ordering. The overall cost should be high.

Try to further simplify the query.